# Firebase auth email verification message

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase auth to control access to my app and it's been working great and was easy to implement.  Now that I'm bringing real testers on, I've got a question.

When a user registers, I'm forcing email verification and that all works fine.  I've even found how to somewhat customize the email that user receives asking them to verify their address.  However, when the user clicks that link, they get a very generic message:

Your email has been verified
You can now sign in with your new account

Is there any way to customize this?  I don't want to do anything particularly fancy - just a more helpful message and maybe a link to return to the app.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the web page that they get to when they click the link, there is no way to customize the existing page. But you can create your own page, and host it (for example on Firebase Hosting). For full documentation on this process, see the documentation on [creating a custom email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

Comment: I think I get it now.  I have to insert my app in to the process a little earlier than I thought to be able to control things in a more user friendly way.  The rest of the app uses Firebase Hosting so it should be reasonably straightforward.  Thanks a lot for your help.